# Why do both of my language stylesheets appear on page load rather than just the default one?

Tags: html, css, lang

I want to make a website which supports two different languages. I made two stylesheets and added some code that will switch when the buttons are clicked:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body.fr :lang(en) {
      display: none;
    }
    body.en :lang(fr) {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="document.body.className='en'">English</button>
    <button onclick="document.body.className='fr'">French</button>
    <p lang="en">This is English</p>
    <p lang="fr">This is French</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, when the page is loaded, all stylesheets appear. I want only one stylesheet appear; the default one is English.

Comment: BTW - "This is French" is not c'est le anglais.

Comment: I think you're going about multi-lingual site solution in quite an unusual way. Why not keep them separate and actually load a different site content entirely rather than trying to switch it via css?

Comment: If you really need to have it as a css solution, just load the stylesheet dynamically via xhr and add it to the bottom of head

Comment: Sounds like something pretty large that shouldn't be left to just CSS. Have you considered using PHP or a JS library to help load things dynamically?

Comment: Surely CSS is for style. The content (HTML) is either written in French or English

Comment: @andyw_ I tried that, but my project requires me to make it of one page. I think it is the best solution

Comment: @aug I've been looking & trying using PHP, it is more bothering. I think it's the best way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a default language to the body tag rather than just the elements you want to be in different languages:

```css
body.fr > p[lang=en] {
display: none;
}
body.en > p[lang=fr] {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="en">
    <button onclick="document.body.className='en'">English</button>
    <button onclick="document.body.className='fr'">French</button>
    <p lang="en">This is English</p>
    <p lang="fr">This is French</p>
</body>
</html>
```