# CSS/HTML adding a second language

Tags: html, css

How would you add a second language to your website only with html/css? I already have the english version in html/css and need the german one to.

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104380/make-multi-language-website-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do this would be to create a copy of every page, but in German, then link the pages together based on language. For example, where your English homepage may link to English pages, your German homepage would link to German duplicates. You would only have to check what language the user wants once, on the homepage.

Comment: so it would be domain.com/en/home domain/de/home and doing this for every page? would are the cons of doing it this way?

Comment: Basically, yes. You would basically have to create two different websites, albeit with the same content. Obviously a drawback would be the time it would take you to translate every single piece of text, but it should be efficient enough. Javascript or JQuery could probably give you a more elegant solution, but this will also work.

Comment: On the other hand, you could try experimenting with the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/)

Comment: thanks man!  you maybe have some resources where the explain the way in javascript/jquery?
ps: i already have the content in german

Comment: I do not profess to be even remotely skilled in Javascript or Jquery, so unfortunately I do not know how to go about this. I would try posting a similar question with javascript/jquery tags, and see where that leads you.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind up voting the answer if it helped, I would appreciate it. I am trying to get more reputation XD